# what this symbol "[=]" means in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning some C++ code which uses boost library. And there are some code like this:

```
getService().post( [=] {...} )
```

getService() is a function which returns an io_service of boost library. I want to know what this symbol "[=]" means in C++?

Comment: Read up on lambda expressions in C++.

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%5B%3D%5D+c%2B%2B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means that the lambda expression captures values by assignment. Another option is to capture by reference using [&]. There are many variations on this, instead of listing them all here, I'll point you at this quality answer: [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: `[]` captures nothing, `[&]` captures everything by reference, `[a, &b]` captures only some variables